# How to Pass Image from Recyclerview to next Activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I really don't know how to do this ....... i've tried some tutorial but not worked for me ... i've already done the this with textview but unable to do this with imageview ...

here is my recyclerview adapter

```
public class RecyclerViewDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewDataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private static String Title = "title";
public ImageLoader mImageLoader;
//List of superHeroes
List<ListOfData> superHeroes;
private Activity context;

public RecyclerViewDataAdapter(List<ListOfData> superHeroes, Activity context) {
    super();
    //Getting all the superheroes
    this.superHeroes = superHeroes;
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_row, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ListOfData superHero = superHeroes.get(position);


    mImageLoader = MyApplication.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    mImageLoader.get(superHero.getImageUrl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imageView1, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));
    holder.imageView1.setImageUrl(superHero.getImageUrl(), mImageLoader);
    holder.textViewName1.setText(superHero.getName());
    //holder.textViewName2.setText(superHero.getName());
    //holder.textViewRank.setText(String.valueOf(superHero.getRank()));
    //holder.textViewRealName.setText(superHero.getRealName());
    //holder.textViewCreatedBy.setText(superHero.getCreatedBy());
    //holder.textViewFirstAppearance.setText(superHero.getFirstAppearance());

    //String powers = "";

    /* for(int i = 0; i<superHero.getPowers().size(); i++){
    powers+= superHero.getPowers().get(i);
}*/

    //holder.textViewPowers.setText(powers);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return superHeroes.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public NetworkImageView imageView1;
    public TextView textViewName1;
    public TextView textViewName2;
    public TextView textViewRank;
    public TextView textViewRealName;
    public TextView textViewCreatedBy;
    public TextView textViewFirstAppearance;
    public TextView textViewPowers;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView1 = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        textViewName1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_title_one);
    /* textViewRank= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRank);
    textViewRealName= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRealName);
    textViewCreatedBy= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCreatedBy);
    textViewFirstAppearance= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewFirstAppearance);
    textViewPowers= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPowers);
    */

        imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ListOfData nextActivitySuperHeroes = (ListOfData) v.getTag();

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MasterDetail.class);
                intent.putExtra(Title, textViewName1.getText().toString());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            /*BehindTheLayoutFragment fragment = new BehindTheLayoutFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.behind_the_layout_fragment, fragment);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit(); */
                //((AppCompatActivity)context).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.behind_the_layout_fragment, fragment).commit();

            }
        });
    }

}}
```

And the next Activity code

```
public class MasterDetail extends AppCompatActivity {
private ImageLoader mImageLoader ;
private String imgUrl = "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/2.jpg";
private static String Title = "title";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.behind_the_layout_fragment);

    Intent i=getIntent();
    String name = i.getStringExtra(Title);


    TextView textView2  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.category_title_one);

    textView2.setText(name);

    mImageLoader = MyApplication.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    NetworkImageView imageView = (NetworkImageView)findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    imageView.setImageUrl(imgUrl, mImageLoader);
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your getBindViewHolder in Adapter, Edit some code like below.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final ListOfData superHero = superHeroes.get(position);

    mImageLoader = MyApplication.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    mImageLoader.get(superHero.getImageUrl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imageView1, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));
    holder.imageView1.setImageUrl(superHero.getImageUrl(), mImageLoader);
    holder.textViewName1.setText(superHero.getName());

    holder.imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MasterDetail.class);
            intent.putExtra(Title, superHero.getName());
            intent.putExtra("URL", superHero.getImageUrl());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

it will be help.

p. s. In MasterDetail, imgUrl already given. if you add

```
imgUrl = i.getStringExtra("URL");
```

it will work.

Comment: Thank you ........ it worked :) 

but will you plz explain what have you done ???

Comment: i simple try to move your OnClickListener in ViewHolder to onBindViewHolder. other part is same. because, in ViewHolder class you only contain variable and findViewById methods, not other code. other code should move to onBindViewHolder.

Answer (score 0):

intent.putExtra("image", listdata[position].getImgId());

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).