# how can pass image from recyclerview adapter to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

want pass image from RecyclerView adapter to another activity .
this is my adapter :

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Deatails> android;


    public DataAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Deatails> android) {
        this.context = context;
        this.android = android;
    }

    @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_row, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

        viewHolder.tv_name.setText(android.get(i).getName());
        viewHolder.tv_version.setText(android.get(i).getVer());
        viewHolder.tv_api_level.setText(android.get(i).getApi());

      Picasso.with(context).load("http://memaraneha.ir/Erfan/images/"+android.get(i).getPic()).resize(500,500)
                .into(viewHolder.tv_image);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return android.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView tv_name,tv_version,tv_api_level;
        private ImageView tv_image;


        public ViewHolder(final View view) {
            super(view);

            tv_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            tv_version = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_version);
            tv_api_level = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_api_level);
            tv_image= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);

            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    Intent intent=new Intent(view.getContext(),Main2Activity.class);
                    String passingdata = tv_name.getText().toString();
                    b.putString("Key", passingdata);
                    intent.putExtras(b);
                    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);



                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

this is my another activity :

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        String receivingdata = b.getString("Key");
        TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        textView.setText(receivingdata);

    }
}
```

so i pass text in  `view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {` section

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    Intent intent=new Intent(view.getContext(),Main2Activity.class);
                    String passingdata = tv_name.getText().toString();
                    b.putString("Key", passingdata);
                    intent.putExtras(b);
                    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

and recive that in another activity with this section

```
 Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        String receivingdata = b.getString("Key");
        TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        textView.setText(receivingdata);
```

i try so many for do same to passing image but not work . seems [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257091/how-to-pass-image-from-recyclerview-to-next-activity) duplicate my problem but have some different in my case and i am confused . if any one can please help

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: @BIW its clear! in onBindViewHolder with picasso library look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't pass images directly in intents. Try to save image locally (or use some library for loading images from web if it's URL image, they implements cache) and pass only URI to this image to activity. Then read image from passed URI.

Comment: @erfan what you mean by pass image? u post a lot of code but don't show the main idea. Anyway, you should pass the url (if your image is stored on server) or the resource id (if it is drawable resource). Then just pass the data as normal. But as your code, why String passingdata = tv_name.getText().toString();? tv_name is your image url?

Comment: @LạngHoàng no its my text and i told i pass this and told how . this is my image url :  Picasso.with(context).load("http://memaraneha.ir/Erfan/images/"+android.get(i).getPic()).resize(500,500)
                .into(viewHolder.tv_image);